# std::shared_ptr and VS2010 utility

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, shared-ptr, node-gyp

I had these two functions in my project:

```
char* V8StringToChar(v8::Handle<v8::String> str);
char* V8StringToChar(v8::Local<v8::Value> val);
```

I converted them to:

```
std::shared_ptr<char> V8StringToChar(v8::Handle<v8::String> str);
std::shared_ptr<char> V8StringToChar(v8::Local<v8::Value> val);
```

And every usage of them to `(&*V8StringToChar(whatever))`

But it giving me Errors:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility(163): 
error C2664: 'CefStringBase<traits>::CefStringBase(const CefStringBase<traits> &) ' :      
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'const   
CefStringBase<traits> &' [C:\CEF\appjs_final\appjs\build\appjs.vcxproj]
```

I am using node-gyp to build the projects in windows.

Comment: Are you sure you converted *every* usage? The error suggests that you're passing a shared pointer to something expecting a naked pointer.

Comment: Great that was the problem. Sorry

Comment: @Mike Is there any case that it would break the application ?